# How to include a PHP file in webpage.(keep clicked links inside div)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im trying to include php(html) file in my website. All pages are loaded with jquery/ajax into a div. Im trying to load another website on my server into the div using php include, For my clients to transfer files to my administrative team. My code isnt working. and How do I keep the website inside the div when the users start clicking around inside of the client portal (web site on my server) without forwarding them out of the window. I dont want to use an iframe so can this be done with jquery or javascript?

Visit my website for a live view https://trillumonopoly.com

Heres the code:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<script>$("#page1").load("https://trillumonopoly.com/clients/index.php body");</script>
</div>
```

Comment: put inside `document . ready`

Comment: Not really, you need to catch all the links using selector, then add listeners to all of them. You will also have to deal with network request in javascript etc which will spent you more time troubleshooting

Comment: theres no way i can use my current ajax script to just use all links or just <a> to open in the div? @AngYC without using a selector.... like css3 when assigning attributes to elements?

Comment: You're going to have to parse the contents of that file in JavaScript and rewrite all the links if they are absolute links. If they are not you can use a <base> html tag. You'll still have to fix case and JavaScript links. IMHO approaches like this are normally more trouble than they are worth. Instead simply iframe the site.

Comment: I tried using an iframe but for some reason the website wont display inside the iframe @NicoWesterdale

Comment: Its probably not showing in an iframe becasue of an `X-Frame-Options` header. Try it and open Web Inspector in Chrome and you'll see a warning. What you can do to get around that is use PHP to proxy the request. Still kinda messy but much easier than doing it in Javascript. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25587483/768732

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the PHP include command.

```
<?php include "file.php" ?>
```